# binary search Tree Quiz Questions

Tags: math, binary-search-tree

Can anybody explain the answer for binary search,

```
A binary search tree (BST) is built by inserting tree following
 values in the given order: 4,25,15,12,20,70,40. 
 The Post Order Traversal will be
          A. 12, 15, 20, 40,70,25, 4
          B. 12,20, 15,40, 70,25, 4
         C. 4,25, 70, 40,15, 12,20
         D. 4,12, 15, 20, 25,40,70
```

I tried for answer. But I dint get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting a value into a BST, you start at the root. If the value is less than the current node's value, go to the left subtree and recurse, otherwise go to the right subtree. If you end up in an empty subtree, create a node at this place.

So the resulting BST for the given order is:

```
4
*
* 25
  * 15
    * 12
      *
      *
    * 20
      *
      *
  * 70
    * 40
      *
      *
    *
```

The post-order traversal visits the nodes in the order *left subtree*, *right subtree*,  *current node*.

Let's say `(n)` describes the traversal of the subtree of node `n`. Then the traversal is:

```
  (4)
= () (25) 4
= (25) 4
= (15) (70) 25 4
= (12) (20) 15 (40) () 70 25 4
= 12 20 15 40 70 25 4
```